# Paginating static assets display in Django

Tags: django, pagination

In a Django project, I have a list of emojis in the `static` folder which I need to display. I want it to be paginated.

Normally, one paginates data objects via passing a queryset to `Paginator` class, or obfuscating all of that and using a `ListView`.

But here, I don't have data objects; I have static assets numbering 200 and I want to use pagination to display them. Maybe the same rules apply, but I can't seem to cleanly wrap my head around this.

Can someone give me an illustrative example of how to achieve this? Thanks in advance. Ideally, I don't want to have to build the static pages manually.

Comment: Can we see your code, please.

Comment: Currently I'm doing it entirely statically; my code is a static template with <img> tags. I have implemented pagination of data objects in my project, although that code would be irrelevant. Maybe I should make a `list` of all emoji names, pass them to the `Paginator` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Model named Emoji and have your static assets' URL placed on a CharField or ImageField.

BTW, Paginator takes any kind of objects. Documentation says it can take a list, tuple, QuerySet, or other sliceable object with a count() or **len**() method.

[docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination)

Perhaps you can create your own python object and pass it to your view using the Paginator class.

Comment: I thought about that. But I'll be incurring relatively expensive DB calls that way. I feel showcasing assets lying in the `static` folder can just be done directly, instead of introducing a DB roundtrip in the middle.

Comment: Paginator takes any kind of objects. Documentation says it can take a list, tuple, QuerySet, or other sliceable object with a count() or __len__() method.  
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/#paginator-objects

Comment: Perhaps you can create your own python object and pass it to your view using the Paginator class.